# Asynchronous operations and promises - what is the difference between these ways of writing code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Saw this as an interview question. What are special consequences of writing promises these ways? Some of these will do the same thing, but what is the special conditions I need to pay attention to?

1. If successful, do `doSomethingElse();` since the inner function is done with currying, you can add special custom parameters.

   ```
   doSomething().then(function () {
     return doSomethingElse(a);
   });
   ```
2. If successful:

   ```
   doSomething().then(function () {
     doSomethingElse(a);
   });
   ```
3. `doSomethingElse()` is a call back function, and this is same as 4(???)

   ```
   doSomething().then(doSomethingElse());
   ```
4. callback function `doSomethingElse()`, same as 3 (?)

   ```
   doSomething().then(doSomethingElse);
   ```

Comment: The function given to number 3 will be evaluated immediately, and will only work as a callback if `doSomethingElse()` returns a function.

Comment: #3 and #4 are not interchangeable. #3 would only work if doSomethingElse returns a function

Comment: Does `a` belong to an outer scope, or is it supposed to be the parameter to the anonymous function in 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2):

**1 vs 2**

In case **1** - you can get the result of `doSomethingElse(a)` in the next `then` in you promise chain.
Like this:

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  return doSomethingElse(a);
}).then(function (doSomethingElseWithAResult /* <-- here */) {
  // Some code
});
```

In case **2** - you always get `undefined` in the next `then` in you promise chain:

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  return doSomethingElse(a);
}).then(function (alwaysUndefined /* <-- here */) {
  // Some code
});
```

**1 vs 3**

You could rewrite **3** like this:

```
doSomething().then(function (doSomethingResult) {
  return doSomethingElse(doSomethingResult);
});
```

So **3** is close to **1**, but in case **3** we do not provide special custom parameters to `doSomethingElse` and we pass the result of `doSomething` to `doSomethingElse` instead of `a`.

**1 vs 4**

The same as **1** vs **3**, assuming that `doSomethingElse` is a curried function at least 2 arguments.

**2 vs 3**

Remembering that we could rewrite **3** like this:

```
doSomething().then(function (doSomethingResult) {
   return doSomethingElse(doSomethingResult);
});
```

The difference is that in case **2** we are not providing special custom parameters to `doSomethingElse` (see **1 vs 3**) and we don't pass the result of `doSomethingElse` to the next `then` in our promise chain (see **1 vs 2**).

**2 vs 4**

The same as **2** vs **3**, assuming that `doSomethingElse` is a curried function at least 2 arguments.

**3 vs 4**

They are the same, assuming that `doSomethingElse` is a curried function of at least 1 argument.
They are not the same if `doSomethingElse` is not a curried function.

Comment: In **1 v 3** "we pass the result of `doSomething` to `doSomethingElse` instead of `a`" is untrue. `doSomethingElse` is evaluated immediately, and (assuming it returns a function) the returned function will be called with the result of `doSomething`. You allude to this a little by calling it a "curried function", but that's not necessarily what's happening here: 3 and 4 both expect `doSomethingElse` to return a function, but 3 is the only case where `doSomethingElse` is executed immediately.

Comment: That's why I've added `is a curried function of at least 1 argument`.

Comment: Note that "currying" refers to [a specific type of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) where you deconstruct a multi-argument function into single-argument functions. That's not quite relevant here: in 3, `doSomethingElse` takes no arguments. If anything, the requirement is that `doSomethingElse` is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), specifically one that returns a function.

Comment: Do you mean that `doSomethingElse` is not the same as `doSomethingElse()` if `doSomethingElse` is a curried function of at least 1 argument?

Comment: Thanks @Bsalex - this is very details. on 1 vs 2 explanation, the second has no return though. And because there's no return, you would always get an undefined that is the data to be passed in right?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to *when `doSomethingElse` is called, what its parameter is, and whether that gets passed along to additional chained promises*.

## 1

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  return doSomethingElse(a);
});
```

This will:

1. Call `doSomething()` *immediately*.
2. Wait for the Promise returned by `doSomething()` to resolve.
3. Call `doSomethingElse()` with the custom argument `a`, presumably from an outer scope. Anything chained after that will receive the return value of `doSomethingElse(a)`.

## 2

```
doSomething().then(function () {
  doSomethingElse(a);
});
```

This will:

1. Call `doSomething()` *immediately*.
2. Wait for the Promise returned by `doSomething()` to resolve.
3. Call `doSomethingElse()` with the custom argument `a`, presumably from an outer scope. Anything chained after that will receive *`undefined`*, not the return value of `doSomethingElse`.

## 3

```
doSomething().then(doSomethingElse());
```

1. Call `doSomething()` *immediately*.
2. Call `doSomethingElse()` *immediately*.
3. Wait for the Promise returned by `doSomething()` to resolve.
4. Call whichever function `doSomethingElse` returned in step 2 with one parameter, the value returned by `doSomething` in step 3. The return value of this function will be passed along to anything chained.

## 4

```
doSomething().then(doSomethingElse);
```

1. Call `doSomething()` *immediately*.
2. Wait for the Promise returned by `doSomething()` to resolve.
3. Call the function `doSomethingElse`, very much like your example #1, except that the function is called with `doSomething()`'s value rather than your own `a` value. The return value of `doSomethingElse` is made available for chaining.